# PyCharm giving cannot find reference and unexpected argument warnings when working with inherited classes from PyQt6 despite code working normally

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt6

I am trying to make a calculator app using PyQt6 and I wanted a QPushButton with fixed size to go into a grid layout. I was going to be using this button a lot so I created my own SquarePushButton class inheriting from QPushButton with an additional setMinimumSize and setMaximumSize already in the **init** function.

I simplified the code as much as possible while replicating the error which is why I am using a QGridLayout for just two widgets.

When I run it, the code works perfectly fine and as expected.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QGridLayout


# class to have a button of fixed size
class SquarePushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText(text)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 50))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(50, 50))


# main window class
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create a text label
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Label")

        # create a button
        btn = SquarePushButton("Button")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonPressed)
        # error: "Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function'"

        # add text label into layout
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 1)

        # sets the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def buttonPressed(self):
        self.label.setText("Pressed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here it gives me an error saying "Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function'"
However if I change how the QWidgets are imported I get a new error at a completely different location, this time the error occurs during layout.addWidget, where it says "unexpected argument" for the last two arguments.
Keep in mind everything still works, its just PyCharm IDE getting mad at me.

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


# class to have a button of fixed size
class SquarePushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText(text)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(50, 50))
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(50, 50))


# main window class
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # create a text label
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Label")

        # create a button
        btn = SquarePushButton("Button")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonPressed)

        # add text label into layout
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(btn, 0, 1)
        # error: "unexpected argument"

        # sets the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def buttonPressed(self):
        self.label.setText("Pressed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Note: It would be easiest to spot if you just copy and pasted the code into your PyCharm IDE because it highlights the supposed error.

I do not understand why there is an error there, everything seems to be working fine so is this a PyCharm bug, PyQt6 bug or am I just using inheritance incorrectly? I am quite new to Python still so sorry if this is really stupid.

Comment: Those are just IDE warnings, they're not *errors*. Also, if minimum and maximum size match, use `setFixedSize()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyQt5 returnPressed.connect "Cannot find reference 'connect' in function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65944846/pyqt5-returnpressed-connect-cannot-find-reference-connect-in-function)

Comment: Yea that answers half of the question.

Comment: Ok so I'm guessing its ok to ignore the warnings as long as my code works? I was just worried there was something that I should not be doing, like some kind of convention. @musicamante

Comment: @AndrewYeh Conventions are important, but, just like any rule, they are not absolute. An algorithm (as advanced as it could be) won't be able to tell you if what you're doing is *just* wrong, unless its syntax is *unequivocally* wrong (and as long as its validation is properly written). They could tell you that, according to their context and knowledge, you're *probably* doing something that's not right. If it actually is right or not is up to your experience. Such warnings are normal, as those functions are dynamic, and the IDE know nothing about them until the program is finally executed.